# jquery autoselect find if name exists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to use autoselect to find some clients in my DB. The goal is to determine if the client exists, if it does not run a function. Right now my function will determine if the first LI matches the value entered. If it does not then it will clear the results and say the client does not exist.

Currently my code only looks at the first returned LI and if it does not match the first LI then it does not consider the client to exist.

This causes a number of problems...if the user decides to click on the 2nd item listed in the autocomplete my code will erase it and say the client does not exist.

Also, I have a function that checks to see when the user hits ENTER or TAB...my goal would be to select the first list item and make that the value if they do this.

I have tried a lot of different things...including :contains...etc. I think I just need another set of eyes at this point.

```
$("#client").autocomplete({
        source: "autoComplete/clientAutoComplete.php",
        minLength: 2,
        change: function (event, ui) {
                //if the value of the textbox does not match a suggestion, clear its value
                if ($(".ui-autocomplete li:first").text() != $(this).val()) {
                        $(this).val('');
                        clientDoesNotExist();
                }
        }
}).on('keydown', function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if ((keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 13) && ($(".ui-autocomplete li:first").text() == $(this).val())) {
                $(this).val($(".ui-autocomplete li:visible:first").text());
        }
});
```

For an example of some of the generated HTML (generated by jQuery) after I typed "mit" into the '#client' input field:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 202.983px; left: 337.15px; display: block; width: 406px;">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">mitch</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">mitch2</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Mitchell56474</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

To help explain a little further, at this point if I were to select "mitch2" (because it is the 2nd LI) my current code would run the clientDoesNotExist(); function. I think I might have to check all LI's to determine if an exact match exists in the returned results.

Comment: Trying to picture what the HTML looks like. Can you maybe post the relevant HTML? Also, can you fix your code formatting while you're in there? Thanks!

Comment: I gave some more details, not sure if that helps. I can understand it might be hard to visualize.

Comment: Still kind of confused, are you wanting to delete *all* values not found in the autocomplete? Are you wanting to check if the client exists by searching all of the li's?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to filter out the li where the text is equal and then grab the first one...

```
$(".ui-autocomplete li a").filter(
    function() {
        return $(this).text() == "mitch2";
    }).first()
```

You'll also notice that I've changed the `$(this).val()` to a static text `"mitch2"`.. the function in the filter call changes the context, so you'll need to save off the `$(this).val()` value in a variable and using it in place of `"mitch2"`.

Update Comment:
* I had omitted the anchor tag that I was using in my test from my post. It appears it's needed, from my testing.

Comment: @mrfras - I fixed your code formatting so that the code is readable. Also, if you use a closure, you can pass in the $(this).val you were referring to. +1